# how to save offline page

Tags: android

I know this kind of silly question. however, I was trying to save an html page in my app, just in case the user has no connectivity. I did the following but failed:

```
  if(CheckConnectivity())
    {mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");}
    else {mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/offline.html");}
```

Then I dragged the offline.html to my assets folder. for CheckConnectivity I did this:

```
      private boolean CheckConnectivity() {
ConnectivityManager CK = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = CK.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Is there something wrong? Do I have to do anything in the manifest?

Comment: How is it failing? ... are you getting an error? or it just always loading the URL?

Comment: No, it doesn't load the Offline URL.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution: 
I got rid of the else statement in the first If. then I placed it under setWebViewClient into:

```
             public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/offline.html");
      }
```